# How can I get returns from APIs faster? I need to get returns from over 400 API endpoints as fast as possible

Tags: python, json, performance, api

I'm trying to get stats on each player from the Premiere League, however, each player has a different API endpoint and there are over 470 players I need to get info for. Is there anyway to make this faster? Preferably just a few seconds.

```
import requests

response1 = requests.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/")
json_general = response1.json()

def get_json_element(element_id):
    response = requests.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/" + str(element_id) + "/")
    return response.json()

def get_fdr(element_id):
    element_id = 1
    points_sum = 0
    fixtures_remaining = len(get_json_element(element_id)["fixtures"])
    ratio = []

    for i in range(fixtures_remaining):
        ratio.append(2 ** i)

    points = 1000 / sum(ratio)

    for i in range(fixtures_remaining):
        output = ((5 - (get_json_element(element_id)["fixtures"][i]["difficulty"])) * (points * ratio[(len(ratio) - 1 - i)] / 5))
        points_sum = points_sum + output
    return points_sum

fdr_dict = {}

for i in range(len(json_general["elements"])):
    fdr_dict.update({json_general["elements"][i]["id"]: get_fdr(json_general["elements"][i]["id"])})

for key, value in fdr_dict.items():
    print(value, key)
```

attempt 2:

import requests
import aiohttp
import asyncio

```
response1 = requests.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/")
json_general = response1.json()


def id_list():
    id_list = []
    for i in range(len(json_general["elements"])):
        id_list.append(json_general["elements"][i]["id"])
    return id_list


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for element_id in id_list():
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_json_element(session, element_id))
            tasks.append(task)

        fdr_list = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    print(dict(fdr_list))


async def get_json_element(session, element_id):
    url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/" + str(element_id) + "/"

    async with session.get(url) as response:
        json_element = await response.json()
        fixtures = json_element["fixtures"]
        return element_id, fixtures

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: use threads or asyncio and make multiple calls concurrently.

Comment: Could you please explain how I would integrate that into my code?

Comment: @acushner I've tried this but it's returning an error. Any ideas? I've put the updated code in the post.

Comment: what kind of errors? another approach might be to use a webscraping framework like scrapy

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've realised that there was a wierd header with the api I was using that needed to be declared.

Answer (score 0):

Reuse the http connection by using a single [session object](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).

Otherwise, the bottleneck is probably the API, so not much you can do on the client side, other than checking if they offer a batch/bulk for your use case.

Comment: I've tried this but it's returning an error. Any ideas? I've put the updated code in the post.

Comment: Perhaps if you give us details about the error.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I've realised that the api I was using had a wierd header that I needed to declare.